# How to call method within another class using PHP

Tags: php

I created two php classes separately. those are Student.php and Main.php this is my code.

**this is my Student.php**

```
<?php

class Student {

private $name;
private $age;

function __construct( $name, $age) {
    $this->name = $name;
    $this->age = $age;
}

function setName($name){
    $this->name = $name;
}

function setAge($age){
    $this->age = $age;
}

function getName() {
    return $this->name;
}

function getAge() {
    $this->age;
}

function display1() {
    return "My name is ".$this->name." and age is ".$this->age;
}

}

?>
```

**this is my Main.php**

```
<?php

class Main{

function show() {
    $obj =new Student("mssb", "24");
    echo "Print :".$obj->display1();
}

}

$ob = new Main();
$ob->show();

?>
```

so my problem is when I call taht show method it gives **Fatal error: Class 'Student' not found** what is the wrong in here. is it necessary to import or something? please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add

```
require_once('Student.php')
```

in your Main.php-file (on top) or before the inclusion of any other file...

Answer (score 2):

The [PHPUnit documentation](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html) says used to say to include/require PHPUnit/Framework.php, as follows:

```
require_once ('Student.php');
```

As of PHPUnit 3.5, there is a built-in autoloader class that will handle this for you:

```
require_once 'PHPUnit/Autoload.php'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use require_once('Student.php') or you can use PHP5 new feature **namespaces** for that. For a example assume your Student.php is in a dir called student. Then as the first line of Student.php you can put

```
<?php    
namespace student;

class Student {
}
```

Then in your Main.php

```
<?php    
use student\Student;

class Main {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's worth taking a look at the PSRs. Particularly [PSR-1](https://github.com/pmjones/fig-standards/blob/psr-1-style-guide/proposed/PSR-1-basic.md)

One of the recommendations is that

> Files SHOULD either declare symbols (classes, functions, constants,
>   etc.) or cause side-effects (e.g. generate output, change .ini
>   settings, etc.) but SHOULD NOT do both

Following this guideline will hopefully make issues like the one you're having less common.

For example, it's common to have one file that is just in charge of loading all necessary class files (most commonly through [autoloading](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php)).

When a script initializes, one of the first things it should do is to include the file in charge of loading all necessary classes.